# Convert foreign characters with accents

Tags: php, compare, diacritics, html-encode

I'm trying to compare some text to the text in a database. In the database any text with an accent is encoded like in HTML (i.e. `&eacute;`) when I compare the database text to my string it doesn't match because my string just shows é. When I use the PHP function htmlentities to encode the string first the é turns into Ã© weird? Using htmlspecialchars doesn't encode the é at all.

How would you suggest I compare é to `&eacute;` as well as all the other accented characters?

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit? Did I make some mistake? I have rolled it back. Please tell me what was wrong with my edit before you roll it back. If I made a mistake I want to learn or fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to send in the correct charset to htmlentities. It looks like you're using UTF-8, but the default is ISO-8859-1. Change it like this:

```
$encoded = htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Another solution is to convert the text to ISO-8859-1 before encoding, but that may destroy information (ISO-8859-1 does not contain nearly as many characters as UTF-8). If you want to try that instead, do like this:

```
$encoded = htmlentities(utf8_decode($text));
```

Comment: thanks! changing the charset to UTF-8 solved it.. one follow up question.. is there a way to set UTF-8 without setting ENT_COMPAT

Comment: @Devin, `ENT_COMPAT` is the default value of `htmlentities` second argument. Technically you could set it to null or you could set it as one of the other 3 values on the [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) page

Comment: after 3 hours of googling and testing various things i finally found this page, you are god :)

Comment: Using `$something = htmlentities($something, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');` before calling `filter_var( $something, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK );` fixed my problem. I thought I just needed to decode the sanitized string, turning it into the right characters, but the actual fix turned out to be placing your code before the sanitizing call.

Answer (score 7):

I'm working on french site, and I also had same problem. This is the function that I use.

```
function convert_accent($string)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode($string)));
}
```

What it does it decodes your string to utf8, than converts everything HTML entities. even tags. But we want to convert tags back to normal, than htmlspecialchars_decode will convert them back. So in the end you will get a string with converted accents without touching tags.
You can use pass through this function your email content before sending it to recipent.

Another issue you might face is that, sometimes with this function the content from database converts to ? . In this case you should do this before running your query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8`");
```

But you might need to do it, it depends on encoding in your table. I hope it helps.

Comment: I added just the :mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8`"); and it worked perfect! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The comparing task is related to the charset and the collation you selected when you create the database or the tables. If you are saving strings with a lot of accents like spanish I sugget you to use charset uft8 and the collation could be the more accurate to the language(english, french or whatever) you're using.

The best thing of using the correct charset in the database is that you can save the string in natural way e.g: my name I can store it as is "Mario Juárez" and I have no need of doing some weird conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into similar issues recently. Followed Emil's answer and it worked fine locally but not on our dev/stage environments. I ended up using this and it worked all around:

```
$title = html_entity_decode(utf8_decode($item));
```

Thanks for leading me in the right direction!