# A weired Bug :: move_upload_file fails to move file when browser is IE 6 or 7 or 9 and hosting is MAC-OSx based

Tags: php, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, special-characters

I am in a trouble because of an issue that i never expected so please help.
(I am pretty new to Stackoverflow so please bear with me if i am doing something wrong)
I am developing a very simple 2 file application that asks user to choose a file in index page and then it uploads file on form submit. Problem occurs when i try to upload a file that has special characters (å, ö, ä) in file name. move_upload_file fails to move file!

I have hosted these files on a MAC OSx server that has support for PHP 5.2. 
File gets upload flawlessly if i am using any other browser then Internet explorer 7, 8 or 9 (haven't tried on IE 6).

So this bug (move_upload_file fails to move file) has something to do with combination: MAC OSx + IE 7,8,9 + Special characters in file name.

To Test, i uploaded files on a Linux server then everything works even in IE 7,8 and 9 :(

I have not written even a single line of javascript code so it is not a JS compatibility issue.

Can any one please shed some light what exactly is wrong with this combination?

Here is the form (index.html):

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="uploadfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is code from fileupload.php:

```
$target_path = "/Volumes/Data/........" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "file has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "failed to upload file";
}
```

With whole day spent with empty stomach to figure out this issue, i will really appreciate if someone can please help and explain why this will happen.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try using a relative path. Instead of `$target_path = "/Volumes/Data/........"` try `$target_path = "Volumes/Data/........"` assuming that your code is being run from your root and that `Volumes` is the next sub-folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
Actually this is not related with path as same path works fine if i use IE 10 or higher instead of IE 7,8,9

Comment: It uploads file with absolute path if browser is not IE 7,8,9.
That is weird :(

Comment: Ok, so it's mostly the special characters that are causing the problem, right?

Comment: Yes .. exactly .. if there are no special characters in file name then everything works fine in every browser :(

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 ? is it present in any of your coded files?

Comment: combination to reproduce this issue is:
MAC OSx Server + IE 7,8 or 9 + special characters in file name. move_uploaded_file fails to upload file with this combination :(

Comment: Also, using characters like `å, ö, ä` for filenames stand at being invalid and it's best to not use them. I would suggest to use a `preg_replace` or some form of filter to not accept filenames containing those characters.

Comment: actually i haven't changed encoding explicitly in my code files. Can it be with some encoding settings at server end as server is located in Sweden?

Comment: yes, striping off these characters is possible but i want to keep that as last option. I am wishing to keep file names, if it possible.

Comment: Even if it could be done, which I doubt very much, I would not use special characters. I just did up a test file called `test_åöä.php` on my Linux server and it did not work. It may work for Windows-based servers, but I can't test it since I don't have one on a Windows server. Even still, the web browser may not even interpret it correctly. You could use a `preg_replace` function to replace the special characters with either `nothing`, a space or an underscore.

Comment: Now, I did create the file on my computer, but that doesn't mean the web browser `and/or` server will accept them or interpret them as being valid.

Comment: Sure, i agree with you. But in this case server is supporting these characters in file name as if browser is not IE 7,8 or 9, file gets uploaded even while having special characters in name. so that is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason finally .. :)
it was because of IE 8 and IE 9 were converting special characters in file names to some alternatives in a weird way .. like ä character was being convert to a¨ (2 characters)

When PHP was trying to upload file name with this ¨ character in file name, MAC OSx was not allowing it. So move_upload_file was failing to move file from tmp directory to the directory where it was supposed to go.

I stripped off unnecessary special characters to fix this problem but finally reached got a satisfactory explanation for myself :)

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Dolly.

I'm assuming that the webapge that you are using is the UTF-8 charset, however these characters are in a different character set, like ISO-8859-1. You can use the PHP function [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert the characters to HTML entities. [This page may also help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782506/php-convert-foreign-characters-with-accents)

Comment: I suggest you post actual code that will `solve` the OP's issue. An uploaded file is an uploaded file, it has nothing to do with special characters being converted to HTML entities. Accessing a file called `test_åöä.php` will remain as `test_åöä.php` on the server. This could be true for `displayed code/text` on a page, but not an uploaded file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Changing the title of the file to html entities may solve OP's problem.

Comment: Actually it is just 2 file application. index.html that has the form and fileupload.php that uploads the file. I have pasted the code in those files in my question

Comment: @DollyGee No problem! If it has solved your issue, please accept this answer by clicking on the green arrow to the left of it.

Comment: You may be right. I'd like to test this theory myself, but it will require some time and I honestly don't have it to spare right now. @DayloStar

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I really appreciate that!
I have spent whole day with empty stomach to build up this theory.. so would love to know if your findings would be different then mine. Thanks again! :)