# How to detect in PHP that pensé is the same as pense

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, collation, diacritics

How can I do a test in PHP to compare two words (one with accent) and detect that is the same word ?

e.g `pensé` vs `pense`

Basically I told it to load certain words from MySQL table, and with MySQL collation settings it loads both versions from db, which is fine, but I want PHP to detect them as the same word too (Like MySQL does in this particular situation).

I assume in PHP it can be done with the [collator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514474/6935528

Comment: yes, that seems to do that, but I am not sure how `es_ES` would affect this, I need to do this test in multiple languages, basically comparind characters in website URLs. In my test the above also worked OK with `en_US`. I will see. Thanks.

Comment: Oh so you can create a function in which you pass 2 words and the locale, something like this `compareWords($word1, $word2, $locale) {}` and then call the function on multiple locales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use the PHP `Collator` class.

`Collator` is part of intl extension - make sure your PHP has intl extension enabled

```
<?php
// Check if Intl extension is loaded
if (!extension_loaded('intl')) {
    exit('Intl extension is not enabled. Please enable it to use Collator.');
}

// Create a Collator object with a specific locale
$collator = new Collator('en_US');

// Set the strength to PRIMARY to ignore accents and case differences
$collator->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);

// Strings to compare
$string1 = 'pensé';
$string2 = 'pense';

// Compare the strings
if ($collator->compare($string1, $string2) == 0) {
    echo "The strings are considered equal.";
} else {
    echo "The strings are not equal.";
}
?>
```

If you are using multiple different languages:

1. Set a general use locale: `$collator = new Collator('root');`
2. Dynamically switch locale if the language context is known, for example a user has a specific language set.

This would look something like this:

```
<?php
function getLocaleFromLanguage($languageCode) {
    $locales = [
        'en' => 'en_US',
        'fr' => 'fr_FR',
        'es' => 'es_ES',
        'de' => 'de_DE',
    ];

    return $locales[$languageCode] ?? 'en_US';
}

function compareStrings($string1, $string2, $languageCode) {
    if (!extension_loaded('intl')) {
        exit('Intl extension is not enabled. Please enable it to use Collator.');
    }

    $locale = getLocaleFromLanguage($languageCode);
    $collator = new Collator($locale);
    $collator->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);

    return $collator->compare($string1, $string2) == 0;
}

// Example usage
$string1 = 'pensé'; // Assume this is Spanish
$string2 = 'pense';

if (compareStrings($string1, $string2, 'es')) {
    echo "The strings are considered equal.";
} else {
    echo "The strings are not equal.";
}
?>
```