# Textarea + special characters not showing correct

Tags: php, html, wordpress, format, textarea

I have a *custom post type* in my wordpress website named **Office**. The post type has

- **Address** :: textarea
- Telephone number :: text field
- Fax :: text field
- Email :: email field

When I type the following in the textarea:

> This is a test
>  with multiple rules 
> België

He saves the following in the database:

```
office_address_location":"This is a testrnwith multiple rulesrnBelgiu00eb
```

How can I make sure he saves the correct format in the database? Or at least show the data in a correct way when I edit the textarea field.

Comment: What charset do you use ? To be sure correct data are read after a write, it's better to always use the same charset for : html front-end, server source code, database encoding, etc.

Comment: maybe its encoding type not set properly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

To maintain line breaks in PHP, you can use the `nl2br($string)` function (documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)). As per the PHP docs:

> nl2br - Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

In order to properly store characters with accents, you need to be using the correct charset. Try using `htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');` and look at the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782506/php-convert-foreign-characters-with-accents).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a problem with encodings. what are the encodings of your webpage and your database table and also your database viewer? Set them all to UTF-8 if you can.